# My webapp still insert " " and null values how can I fix this?

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I have Mysql table which contains questions and answers

```
        CREATE TABLE question(
        id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        ttype INT NOT NULL,
        content VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
        a1 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        a2 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        a3 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        a4 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        a5 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
       correctAnswer VARCHAR(10)
       )
```

and I'm using (MVC JSP servlet) to insert in the database

my addquestion() in DAO class is

```
 public int Addquestion(Question q){
 int type = q.getTtype();
 String content = q.getContent();
 String a1 = q.getA1();
 String a2 = q.getA2();
 String a3 = q.getA3();
 String a4 = q.getA4();
 String a5 = q.getA5();
 String correctAnswer =q.getCorrectAnswer();

 Connection con = null;
 PreparedStatement insertQuestion = null;
 int result = 0;
 try{
     con = DBConnection.createConnection();
     insertQuestion = con.prepareStatement("insert into question(ttype,content,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,correctAnswer) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
     insertQuestion.setInt(1,type);
     insertQuestion.setString(2,content);
     insertQuestion.setString(3, a1);
     insertQuestion.setString(4, a2);
     insertQuestion.setString(5, a3);
     insertQuestion.setString(6, a4);
     insertQuestion.setString(7, a5);
     insertQuestion.setString(8, correctAnswer );

     result = insertQuestion.executeUpdate();


 }
 catch(SQLException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
 }


  return result;
  }
```

the problem is I thought that (NOT NULL) will be enough to return error (result=0) when the (web App) submit empty form. but my database still takes null values (or "" ) ?

(Note: I'm not sure what the HTML empty form return when I submit null or "")

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will definitely add `null or ""` values in database. Why because  prepared statement will create SQL something like this (If you want to see final query, put `System.out.println(insertQuestion);` before `executeUpdate()`)

```
insert into question(ttype,content,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,correctAnswer) VALUES (1,'test','test','test','test','test','test','test')
```

now let say you have put no values on HTML form for some `not null` fields than query will become

```
(1,'test','test','test','test','','','test')
```

and `empty String ("")` is not equal to `null` even if you put `null` in HTML form though it will take it as

```
(1,'test','test','test','test','null','null','test')
```

and it will insert into database (No error).

So it is better to put validation on client side(Javascript, jQuery) for not null fields instead validating it on server.

Hope this helps :)